# Removing punctuation, non-Arabic words and digits except dots and commas

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to write a regex that do the following:
Removing punctuation, non-Arabic words and digits except dots and commas.

I would like to have two separated regex to do the following in java:

1. Removing punctuation and digits except dots and commas.
2. Removing non-Arabic words except dots and commas.

Note that I know the following, but I couldn't exclude dots and commas from the regx to not be matched:

`"[\\p{P}\\p{Digit}]"` --> for removing digits and punctuation regex

`"[^\\p{InArabic}]+"` --> for removing non Arabic letters regex

Example:

العمر (age): هو الشيء الوحيد الذي كلما زاد نقص.

After performing the two regex, we should get the following:
 العمر هو الشيء الوحيد الذي كلما زاد 
نقص.

Any help will be appreciated because I tried many possibilities, but all of them didn't work.

Comment: Posting examples of input and expected output/result could be very useful for us while creating and testing our regexes (not everyone here uses Arabic characters).

Comment: Good point, here is an example:
العمر (age): هو الشيء الوحيد الذي كلما زاد نقص.
After performing the two regex, we should get the following:
العمر هو الشيء الوحيد الذي كلما زاد نقص.

Comment: Since not all of users read comments you shouldn't post such important information separately from question. Instead use [[edit]] button under your question and place this information there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a negated character class combined with the set intersection operator `&&`:

```
"[^.,&&[\\p{P}\\p{Digit}]]+"
```

matches digits and punctuation except commas and periods.

For your second problem, just add the comma/period to the already-negated charclass:

```
"[^\\p{InArabic}.,]+"
```

To combine both, you can use

```
"[^.,&&[\\P{InArabic}\\p{P}\\p{Digit}]]+"
```

Comment: I didn't get your first regex. It means remove everything but punctuation, digit, dot, comma. Isn't?

Comment: @SabujHassan: No, `\p{P}` matches any punctuation character and `\P{P}` inverts that, matching any character that's *not* a punctuation character. So `[^\P{P}]` then matches the same as `\p{P}`. But since we're now using a negated character class, we can subtract characters that we don't want to include in the match by adding them to the character class.

Comment: If I want to make the two regx in one regx that do the same, how I can write it?

Comment: @Eng.Lolina: I was away from my PC for a few days, have now updated the regex (and corrected the first one that wasn't working correctly for me).

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, can you please tell me what (+) for?

Comment: @Eng.Lolina: That's a quantifier, meaning "One or more matches of the previous token", so if there are several consecutive digits (for example), they can be removed with a single operation.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to exclude some elements from set you can use [intersection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersection_%28set_theory%29) of this set with set which contains everything beside elements you want to exclude (it is [complement set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_%28set_theory%29)). In other words:

> A `\` B = A `∩` B<sup>c</sup>

In regex intersections of character classes `[...]` represents `&&`, so you can try something like

1. `"[\\p{P}\\p{Digit}&&[^,.]]"`
2. `"[\\P{InArabic}&&[^,.]]"` (`\\P{xxx}` is negation of `\\p{xxx}`, and vice-versa)

Comment: Very useful information as I am new to regex, thank you so much, it works for me also. Your help is appreciated.

Comment: I am glad you like it :)

Comment: If I want to make the two regx in one regx that do the same, how I can write it?

Comment: @Eng.Lolina I'm not sure what you mean by "two regx in one regx" but maybe you are looking for OR operator which is `|`. You can try something like `regex1|regex2` to include matches from both regexes.

Comment: The first regex "[\\p{P}\\p{Digit}&&[^,.]]" is removing punctuation and digits except . and , while the second one "[\\P{InArabic}&&[^,.]]" is removing non-Arabic characters except . and , NOW I want a regex that remove punctuation, digits and non-Arabic characters except . and ,

Comment: @Eng.Lolina Have you tried `[\\p{P}\\p{Digit}\\P{InArabic}&&[^,.]]`?

Comment: Really you helped me a lot, hope you achieve what you want.